# Error creating sequence object in oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a beginner who has just started a database.
I am currently creating a sequence with oracle 19c and oracle sql developer,
but since yesterday I have been getting an error in the start with part.
I would be so grateful if you could give me any hints or answer..thank you so much!!

[image]

```
create sequence user_seq
start with 0
increment by 1
minvalue 0;
```

Comment: and what is the error???

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-sequence/oracle-create-sequence/

Comment: your last create works fine for me, so if you don't show the errors, nobody can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no error here. Sequence will be created unless there's an object in your schema with the same name.

If you're worried about the *red underline* which suggests that there's an error in your code, it is SQL Developer which wrongly identifies it (the error). If you keep the mouse pointer on it, you'll see what SQL Developer says (left hand side of the following screenshot):

[image]

If you "move" the offending line elsewhere, e.g. into the 1st line, there's no error indicator any more (right hand side of the screenshot).

Shortly: don't worry about it.